# Show that different right cosets of different subgroups are different.

Tags: abstract-algebra

For $H, H'$ subgroups of $G$, and $H \neq H'$, show that $Hg \neq H'g'$ for each $g, g' \in G$.

I think I want to show the contrapositive, that if for some $g, g'$ we have $Hg = H'g'$ then $H = H'$. But I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Suppose you have a set $X$, and I told you $X=gH$ for some $g\in G$ and subgroup $H\le G$. How can you determine $H$ from $X$?

Comment: @anon $H = g^{-1}X$, so are you saying that I should say $H = H'g'g^{-1}$?

Comment: What can you conclude from $H=H'g'g^{-1}$?

Comment: @anon I'll let it simmer a bit. I'll get back to you when I think of something.

Comment: The only coset of a subgroup containing the identity is the subgroup itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
gH = g'H' \implies g'^{-1}gH = H'
$$

Since $e \in H'$ there must exist some $h \in H$ such that $g'^{-1}gh = e$.

$$
g'^{-1}gh = e \implies g'^{-1}g = h^{-1}
$$

The right hand side is in $H$ so the left hand is also in $H$, so $g'^{-1}gH = H = H'$

Comment: (The question was about right cosets instead of left cosets, but same argument.)

Comment: Yes sorry, I only realized that after I posted.